# I want to start a new activity when I click on a listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onitemclicklistener

I properly set the OnItemClickListener but it crashes when I click on one of the list item. I want to know if it can even be done

Here is the code

Update:

```
 public class Inbox extends ListActivity {

    private static String[] numbers;
    private static String[] content;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox_list);
        DictionaryOpenHelper helper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(this,"MyTable", null, 2);
        SQLiteDatabase database  = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable", null);

        numbers = new String[c.getCount()];     
        content = new String[c.getCount()];
            c.moveToFirst();
            int count = 0;
            do{
                numbers[count] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PhoneNumber"));
                content[count] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Message"));
                count++;
            }
            while(c.moveToNext());

            database.close();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                numbers));
    this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener);
        }
    private OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Inbox.this, ContDisplay.class);
            intent.putExtra("number", numbers[arg2]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

inside Oncreate:

```
this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Paste your code and log cat errors.

Comment: post the code and logcat

Comment: Can you show us some code? Like what's inside your OnItemClickListener. And maybe the stacktrace that displays the error?

Comment: It can be done, as Hardy says if we can't see your code we can't help.

Comment: Did you set the button listener correctly ? Is the activity defined in the manifest ?

Comment: I think you need to use `setOnItemSelectedListner`.

Comment: I have uploaded the code. I have to access the database and set the setListAdapter. Should I be using new Thread or something?

Comment: This one is giving you exception `numbers[(int) arg0.getAdapter().getItemId(arg2)]` Try to change it with  `numbers[arg2]` .

Comment: "crash" doesnt exists. It had an exception, which appears on your logcat. Paste that exception and people can help you

Comment: @user2409569 is your activity extends with ListActivity?

Comment: Always appreciate the helpers...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arg0.getAdapter().getItemId(arg2)` should be replaced with `arg2`, because arg2 is position of clicked list's element. I think you getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because you are trying to get element of array not by element's position, but by element's id! Element's id could be for example 100203102031230.

Comment: yeah fixed now. Was just trying to associate clicked item with number, and number with message sent from that number.